# Tensorflow Macro F1 Score for multiclass and also for binary classification

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification, metrics, multiclass-classification

I am trying to train  2 1D Conv neural networks - one for a multiclass classification problem and second for a binary classification problem. One of my metrics has to be Macro F1 score for both problems. However  I am having a problem using `tfa.metrics.F1Score` from tensorflow addons.

## Multiclass classification

I have 3 classes encoded as 0, 1, 2.

The last layer of the network and the compile method look like this (`int_sequeces_input` is the input layer):

```
preds = layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax")(x)
model = keras.Model(int_sequences_input, preds)


f1_macro = F1Score(num_classes=3, average='macro')
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy',f1_macro])
```

However when I run `model.fit()`, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 3 and 1. Shapes are [3] and [1]. for '{{node AssignAddVariableOp_7}} = AssignAddVariableOp[dtype=DT_FLOAT](AssignAddVariableOp_7/resource, Sum_6)' with input shapes: [], [1].
```

##### shapes of data:

X_train - (23658, 150)

y_train - (23658,)

## Binary classification

I have 2 classes encoded as 0,1

The last layer of the network and the compile method look like this (`int_sequeces_input` is the input layer):

```
preds = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
model = keras.Model(int_sequences_input, preds)

print(model.summary())

f1_macro = F1Score(num_classes=2, average='macro')
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy',f1_macro])
```

Again, when I run `model.fit()` I get error:

```
ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 2 and 1. Shapes are [2] and [1]. for '{{node AssignAddVariableOp_4}} = AssignAddVariableOp[dtype=DT_FLOAT](AssignAddVariableOp_4/resource, Sum_3)' with input shapes: [], [1].
```

##### shapes of data:

X_train - (15770, 150)

y_train - (15770,)

So my question is: how to evaluate both of my models using macro F1 score? How can I fix my implementation to make it work with `tfa.metrics.F1Score`? Or is there any other way to calculate macro F1 score without using `tfa.metrics.F1Score`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [usage example](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/F1Score#usage) from its doc page.

```
metric = tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=3, threshold=0.5)
y_true = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 0, 0],
                   [1, 1, 0]], np.int32)
y_pred = np.array([[0.2, 0.6, 0.7],
                   [0.2, 0.6, 0.6],
                   [0.6, 0.8, 0.0]], np.float32)
metric.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
```

You can see that it expects the label to be in one-hot format.

But given the shapes you mentioned above:

```
shapes of data:
X_train - (23658, 150)

y_train - (23658,)
```

It looks like your labels are in index format. Try converting them to one hot with `tf.one_hot(y_train, num_classes)`. You'll also need to change your loss to `loss='categorical_crossentropy'`.

Comment: Thank you.  I am doing text classification and the labels are encoding of FALSE - 0, MISLEADING -1, TRUE - 2 in the case of multiclass classification. In the case of binary classification it's FALSE - 0, TRUE - 1. I guess it's ordinal data and therefore I am afraid that one-hot encoding might negatively impact the performance so I would prefer to keep it encoded in the current way (or maybe I am wrong?). And regarding the loss - should it be changed also in the case of binary classification or just multiclass classification?

Comment: "Ordinal data, one-hot encoding might negatively impact the performance". No the loss is insensitive to the order this will make no difference on the result.  For the binary classifier you may need to convert it to a multiclass-classifier with 2 outputs.

Comment: So in the case of binary classification, the output layer will have 2 neurons and sigmoid or softmax activation? And categorical crossentropy loss?

Comment: Yes. Softmax activation.

Comment: Thank you. One more question: I guess I need to pass `tf.one_hot(y_train, num_classes)` to `model.fit()` instead of `y_train`. But then doing that for `y_test` i.e.   `tf.one_hot(y_test, num_classes)` how can I be sure that `y_test` will be transformed the same way?

Comment: Ok, I probably should not do it that way, because I get `InvalidArgumentError`. When should I apply `tf.one_hot` and make it transform `y_train` and also `y_test`?

Comment: Or maybe doing one hot encoding with sklearn's OneHotEncoder in the data preprocessing phase would do the trick...